# No module named 'distutils.util' for python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have the following docker file and I got the following error. Can anyone help me?

```
FROM ubuntu:focal AS systemdependencies
RUN    apt update \
    && apt --yes upgrade \
    && apt --yes install software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository 'ppa:deadsnakes/ppa' \
    && apt-get --yes install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" requirements_system.txt | tr "\n" " ") \
    && apt-get --yes autoremove && apt-get --yes autoclean && apt-get --yes clean

RUN    apt-get update && apt-get --yes install python3-pip 
RUN    python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I have following in requirements_system.txt file:

```
software-properties-common
python3.6 python3.6-dev
openssl
```

I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [pythondependencies 5/5] RUN    python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                                                          1.1s ------
 > [pythondependencies 5/5] RUN    python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip:
#14 0.989 Traceback (most recent call last):
#14 0.989   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
#14 0.990     "__main__", mod_spec)
#14 0.990   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
#14 0.990     exec(code, run_globals)
#14 0.990   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
#14 0.990     from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
#14 0.990   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
#14 0.990     from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
#14 0.990   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
#14 0.991     from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
#14 0.991   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
#14 0.991     from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
#14 0.991   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in <module>
#14 0.991     from distutils.util import strtobool
#14 0.991 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is any package missing in you system.

- First, find the proper `distutils.util` in your system by `apt-cache search distutils`.
- Then, install the suitable package dependent the search list, such as `python3-distutils-extra`